My Roblox frame isn't going to the next frame?
I am making a game where in a computer in the game I click a button it would open a frame where I enter a username then press enter to take me to an another frame where I type out a message then press press submit to enter it in a queue where and claim the note to deliver it to the rightfull peron (whatever person typed in the first frame) and if there is no username have it deliverd to an npc. my problem is the enter button to take me from frame one to frame two dont work
local NextButton = script.Parent
local ScreenGui = NextButton.Parent
local UsernameTextBox = ScreenGui.Frame.UsernameTextBox
-- List of NPC names
local npcNames = {"ROBLOX", "Bacon", "builderman"}
-- Assuming you have a RemoteEvent for sending messages to NPCs
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("RemoteEvent")

UsernameTextBox.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard and input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Return then
        local username = UsernameTextBox.Text
        if username == "" then
            -- If username is empty, randomly select an NPC
            local randomIndex = math.random(1, #npcNames)
            local randomNPC = npcNames[randomIndex]
            print("Randomly selected NPC:", randomNPC)
            -- Now you can use 'randomNPC' as the recipientUsername or do further processing

            -- Example: Send a message to the randomly selected NPC
            local message = ScreenGui.Frame.MessageTextBox.Text .. randomNPC
            RemoteEvent:FireServer("SendMessageToNPC", message, randomNPC)
        else
            print("Enter key pressed")
            NextButton.MouseButton1Click:Fire()
        end
    end
end)

hierarchy
I expected it to take me to the second frame to type the message.

Please show us the logs in the Output Window or Developer Console so we know what's working, what isn't, and any errors or warnings with your code.

the output/console is blank when it came to the frames

Your issue is coming from this line: NextButton.MouseButton1Click:Fire()

The MouseButton1Click event doesn't have a :Fire() method. You will have to bind another event to the function that switches the page (the function binded to MouseButton1Click).
To do this just make a Bindable Event and connect BindableEvent.Event to the function that switches the page.
